# Gantt view is missing when using the starter master page

Tags: master-page

I am using the starter master page in one of my projects but the Gantt view does not show up for a list. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you not have the proper admin access?

Comment: I do. I was missing the s4-workspace div id.

Comment: @iHeartDucks: Can you post the solution to your question as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add a div with id "s4-workspace"